# How to sort the list based on the string?

Tags: python

Here I am try to sort the list of strings based on the one string, Here my test cases,

**First Case:**

```
par_str = "abcd"
list_str = ['bb','ba','ab']

sorted(list_str, key=par_str)
```

**Output:** `['ab','ba','bb']`

**Second Case:**

```
par_str = "bacd"
list_str = ['bb','ba','ab']

sorted(list_str, key=par_str)
```

**Output:** `['bb','ba','ab']`

From the First case list order changed based on `par_str` string. And Second test case the list order no change because it has same priority. So How to write above logic. I have tried but I am getting an error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: The `key` argument in `sorted` must be a callable, as in *not* a string.

Comment: What is the actual size of `par_str`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary My actual string is "a-z".

Comment: @dhana in `sorted(list_str, key=par_str)`, `key=par_str` is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a mapping between characters and ranks, and use that information in `key` function.

```
>>> par_str = "abcd"
>>> order = {c:i for i, c in enumerate(par_str)} # <------------
>>> order
{'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'b': 0, 'd': 3}
>>> list_str = ['bb','ba','ab']
>>> sorted(list_str, key=lambda s: [order[c] for c in s])
['ab', 'ba', 'bb']

>>> par_str = "bacd"
>>> order = {c:i for i, c in enumerate(par_str)} # <-----------
>>> order
{'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'b': 0, 'd': 3}
>>> list_str = ['bb','ba','ab']
>>> sorted(list_str, key=lambda s: [order[c] for c in s])
['bb', 'ba', 'ab']
```

Comment: @dhana which line you don't understand. it is sorted on the basis of list of numbers. Very char is mapped to a number using order as list.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I didn't understand sorted method.

Comment: @dhana, The return value of the `key` function is used as comparison keys.

Comment: @dhana try `>>> [1, 2, 3] < [1, 3, 3]` on your system. Also try: `>>> [order[c] for c in s]`

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> par_str = "abcd"
>>> list_str = ['bb','ba','ab']
>>> 
>>> def key_func(s):
...     return [par_str.index(i) for i in s]
... 
>>> sorted(list_str, key=key_func)
['ab', 'ba', 'bb']
>>> par_str = "bacd"
>>> sorted(list_str, key=key_func)
['bb', 'ba', 'ab']
```

If `par_str` is long enough it will be worthwhile using the helper `dict` in @falsetru's answer.

It's preferable to use a full function definition rather than a lambda if you would like to be able to test your key function

Here is a little trick to make the key function really fast. (The dict is subtly different to @falsetru's)

```
>>> par_str = "abcd"
>>> list_str = ['bb','ba','ab']
>>> sorted(list_str, key=lambda s, trans={ord(c): i for i, c in enumerate(par_str)}:s.translate(trans))
['ab', 'ba', 'bb']
>>> par_str = "bacd"
>>> sorted(list_str, key=lambda s, trans={ord(c): i for i, c in enumerate(par_str)}:s.translate(trans))
['bb', 'ba', 'ab']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer +1 for you